# How to display hamburger menu items next to each other in bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using a bootstrap navbar with a hamburger menu on screens smaller than 767px. When the menu icon is clicked on small screens it displays my list of items in their own row format but I want them to be next to each other instead. I am sure it is in bootstraps default CSS that comes with using its class, but I am unsure of which property or how to find bootstraps default CSS properties for each class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.0/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" integrity="sha512-3AxW5HcDzhL9MJdO2mpDEGEZ6NcCg/pDSa8R2kH5gwEA4r48RxZf0nPITA1NfX1pNA6a/eAayX+yW6QopF4jeg==" crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="navbar-items">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#home">
      test
        <!-- <CgProfile className="profile-icon" /> -->
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#home">
      test
        <!-- <HiOutlineHeart className="heart-icon" /> -->
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#home">
      test
        <!-- <IoCartOutline className="cart-icon" /> -->
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to give these classes `navbar navbar-expand-lg` to *nav* container, it will make your navbar responsive.

Second, you can use `d-flex`to place items next to eachother.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.0/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" integrity="sha512-3AxW5HcDzhL9MJdO2mpDEGEZ6NcCg/pDSa8R2kH5gwEA4r48RxZf0nPITA1NfX1pNA6a/eAayX+yW6QopF4jeg==" crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<!-- EDITED HERE -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <!-- EDITED HERE -->
  <ul class=" navbar-nav d-flex">
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link " href="#home ">
      test
        <!-- <CgProfile className="profile-icon " /> -->
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link " href="#home ">
      test
        <!-- <HiOutlineHeart className="heart-icon " /> -->
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
      <a class="nav-link " href="#home ">
      test
        <!-- <IoCartOutline className="cart-icon " /> -->
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```